# rootVisible=false does not work

Tags: extjs, tree

::I created a dynamic tree panel in `jstree`, but i can't hide the root of the tree. When `rootVisible=false` in tree panel, the root is invisible, but status `code 200` is shown. How can I hide the root of the tree?

I have a static panel in view(Section1).I defined a `listener(afterrender.handler="LoadTree();")` for Section1.

```
var h=0;
function LoadTree() {

    if (h < 2) {

                var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400,
                    collapsed:true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    useArrows: true,
                    title: 'test',
                    id: 'Tree' + String(h),
                    rootVisible:false                         
                });

                tree.setRootNode({
                    text: 'root'
                });

                var root = tree.getRootNode();
                for (var g = 0; g < 2; g++) {
                    var A= root.appendChild(
                        {
                            text: '1'
                        });

                    for (var t = 0; t <3; t++)
                    {
                        var B= A.appendChild(
                            {
                                text: '2'
                            });
                    }
                }
                App.Section1.add(tree);
                h++;
                LoadTree();
            }
    }
```

Comment: What version of jsTree you are using? What is the code 200 status of? Can you provide a snapshot of what you try to achieve?

Comment: I use version 2.3. status code is {}. I created dynamic tree panel and added childNodes in a for loop

Comment: Can you add the script to your question?

Comment: I added script to my question, please help me.

Comment: I can't because it is not `jsTree` you tagged you question with. It is ExtJs tree. I changed your tag, hope you will find the answer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include ... *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). - I am unable to reproduce your "status 200".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what

> status code 200

means, but I tune up your code abit, all works just fine.

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15lm)

Check it out and if any issues appear update your question / my fiddle to reproduce it.

Comment: I still have the error. please suggest another way to me.